# Propagate methods from grand-child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a dumb component, `List`, that has some methods defined like this:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    ...

    scrollTo() {
    ...
    }

    clear() {
    ...
    }
}
```

I then use it in a Parent Component, let's say `UsersList`:

```
class UsersList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <List {...this.props} {...} />;
    }
}
```

Then I have as a Parent I have `FriendsPage`:

```
class FriendsPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <UsersList ref={(ref) => { this.usersListRef = ref; }} {...} />
        );
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `this.usersListRef.scrollTo()` for example in `FriendsPage`, without having to define the methods of `List` in `UsersList`.

I can pass a prop called `listRef` and use it as `ref={this.props.listRef}` but I was wondering if another solution exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check the documentation on this one, and there is a paragraph about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components.

Basically, it is the solution I envisaged in my question, using a `listRef` and passing it down to wherever my `List` Component is.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can't call functions of a child and that would also be against the idea of react. Ideally your `<UserList>` component accepts a prop that makes it know where to scroll to. Something like:

```
class UserList extends React.Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        const {activeItem} = this.props;
        this.scrollTo(activeItem);
    }

    scrollTo = activeItem => {
        // calculate position of active item to scroll to
        // and scroll to it
    }
}
```

And then your `<FriendsPage>` could look something like this:

```
class FriendsPage extends React.Component {

    handleSelectionChange = selected => {
        // triggered when the selected element in the list changes
        this.setState({selected});
    }

    render() {
        const {selected} = this.state;

        return <UserList activeItem={selected} {...this.props} />;
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell if this is 100% the approach you need as you did not provide many details about the conditions that lead to scrolling.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to not have to implement some logic in my `List` Component as it is very dumb and would like to keep this way, especially as it could have a lot of methods doing different things, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Bhullnatik If you want your `List` component to be dumb it shouldn't have any additional methods at all. This way it is obviously not dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, I'm not sure if I'm getting It right, but you should read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

In React, the idea is to go top-down. As you need the UsersList component to do something when user interacts with List component, then you should define the function in UsersList and pass that function as a prop to the List Component.

For example:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    <div onClick={this.props.scrollTo}
}
```

I then use it in a Parent Component, let's say UsersList:

```
class UsersList extends React.Component {

    scrollTo(){
      do something...
    }

    render() {
        return <List scrollTo={() => this.scrollTo()} {...this.props} {...} />;
    }
}
```

Then I have as a Parent I have FriendsPage:

```
class FriendsPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <UsersList {...} />
        );
    }
}
```